# WordPress: Unable to install or update plugins

Tags: wordpress, macos, xampp

I am trying to install plugins but I keep getting error

> Could not create directory.
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/

I added read and write permission to the WordPress folder but i am still unable to update or install plugins. Currently running MAC OS mojave

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to open terminal
- navigate to directory

  $ cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/
- Try the chmod command. For example, if you have a directory name mydir, the following command will enable read/write for that mydir recursively.

  $ chmod -R +rw plugins

That's it.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me.

Comment: @NikedoCampbell glad to know that.

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling WordPress in Updates -> re-install, it does not impact any website information in any way